# SQL Server Check for IsNull and for Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull, divide-by-zero

I have the following:

```
set @SomeVariable = @AnotherVariable/isnull(@VariableEqualToZero,1) - 1
```

If @VariableEqualToZero is null it substitutes the 1.  I need it to substitute 1 if @VariableEqualToZero = 0 as well.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SET @SomeVariable = @AnotherVariable / COALESCE(
        CASE 
             WHEN @VariableEqualToZero = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE @VariableEqualToZero
        END, 1) - 1
```

Comment: instead of coalasce() and Case() just use a CASE with isnull? ISNULL([@VariableEqualToZero],0) = 0 THEN 1

Answer (score 42):

If you're using SQL Server, you can probably use a `NULLIF` statement?
i.e. set the value to `NULL` if it's `0` then set it to `1` if it's `NULL` - should catch for both 0's and NULLs:

```
SET @SomeVariable = @AnotherVariable/ISNULL(NULLIF(@VariableEqualToZero,0),1) - 1
```

Comment: +1 `NULLIF()` is the way to go (and it's Standard SQL too, so I'd be tempted to replace `ISNULL()` with `COALESCE()` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
set @SomeVariable = @AnotherVariable /
(case when isnull(@VariableEqualToZero, 0) = 0 then 1 else
@VariableEqualToZero end) - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You use CASE

instead of

```
ISNULL(@VariableEqualToZero,1)
```

use

```
CASE WHEN @VariableEqualToZero IS NULL OR @VariableEqualToZero = 0 THEN 1 ELSE @VariableEqualToZero END
```

COALESCE and ISNULL are essentially just shortcuts for a CASE statement.
You can consult the help for the syntax of CASE.