# sql is there a command to check if a row is zero?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I need to check if a row is zero. For nulls I usually use isnull() but my rows are never null. If there is such a command, I would use it like this:

```
select * from maintable where column1 = iszero(@param,column1)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to check if a column that contains integers contains a 0 value?

Comment: What do you mean "IsZero"?  Why would you just not use `select * from maintable where column1  = 0?`

Comment: maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/580364/405117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your looking for something to work in the same way as `IsNull()` you could define your own function

```
create function IsZero(@value int, @default int)
    returns int
as
begin

    if (@value <> 0)
        return @value

    return @default
end
```

Example of usage

```
select 
    Returns5 = dbo.Iszero(5, 10),
    Returns10 = dbo.Iszero(0, 10)
```

or in your case

```
select * from maintable where column1 = IsZero(@param,column1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   maintable 
WHERE  column1 = CASE @param 
                     WHEN 0 THEN column1 
                     ELSE @param 
                 END
```

This will give you the record in the `maintable` with where `column1` equals the `@param` variable. If the `@param` variable is 0 then it will return all records in the `maintable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from maintable
where column1 = @param or @param = 0
```